# Is navigator.virtualKeyboard no longer available in android chrome?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

My webpage that used navigator.virtualKeyboard is not working anymore. Did I miss the memo, have they [re]moved the virtual keyboard api?

I have exactly 2 devices available for testing, neither have the (virtualKeyboard in navigator). They both used to work fine. Obviously the windows desktop chrome does not have such.

Can anyone confirm if virtual keyboard api has changed?

Comment: you mean [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VirtualKeyboard_API) - seems to be classed as experimental, but that usually just means that mozilla haven't implemented it - the main takeaway though is, it's only available in a secure context

Comment: `Obviously the windows desktop chrome does not have such.` according to the link above, you're obviously mistaken

Comment: @JaromandaX Sorry, where is the virtual keyboard in windows chrome?

Comment: Take a look at the browser compatibility table in the link

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, but how do I test it in desktop chrome?

Comment: not important is it? I was just pointing out that it CAN be available on a desktop ... like a touch screen with no keyboard type situation

Comment: @JaromandaX Testing is very important, actually this whole question is here because I could not test this without another phone. Documentation is of no use if the only information about a feature is a check on compatibility chart.

Answer (score 0):

As the first comment suggested, the **virtual keyboard api** is only available in **secure context** (**HTTPS://**), that was also the factor in my environment. I will leave this as an answer for those wondering the same issue.